# STL independent initializer list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, stl, initializer-list

I am little bit confused about initializer lists.

I think that initializer list is something what is part of C++:

```
struct Something { char c0, c1; };

Something something = { 'H', 'W' };
```

Analogically with arrays etc. And there is something connected (in my eyes) with STL (in header `<initializer_list>`),  called `std::initializer_list<T>`, which matches initializer lists as e.g. method params, etc.

```
std::initializer_list<char> list = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
```

Now my confusion:

```
auto match = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
```

When I look what is `auto` interpretation (in MSVC 2015), it is `std::initializer_list<char>`.

**So my questions are:**

Where is the line between C++ language and STL library?

Is there some directive specifying how should be initializer list (in C++ meaning) interpreted?

Could be interpretation changed e.g. from `std::initializer_list<T>` into `T[]`?

Comment: The language and the standard library work together. The compiler can create and pass an object of e.g. `std::initializer_list` when needed. However, the first example you show, when you're initializing the structure, then no `std::initializer_list` is created. It's a direct initialization of the structure.

Comment: We're assuming that you mean "Standard Library" when you wrote "STL".

Comment: @MSalters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library

Comment: @user4663214: When it comes to C++, Wikipedia is a pretty bad source. The primary source is of course the ISO C++ committee itself, www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/, but you find quite a few of those people here on StackOverflow making this a pretty good secondary source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers partially based on [MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/34e7207c-926e-4bd3-a029-62fc09f2a13e/initializer-list-interpretation?forum=vclanguage).

> Where is the line between C++ language and STL library?

The line between standard library and pure C++ is a little bit noisy.
It is situated in part of library called LSL, Language Support Library.
The line exist in following example: *Allocation returns `std::bad_alloc`.* So to be pure from c++ language viewpoint, `std::bad_alloc` could be supressed using direct allocation via OS API.
Similarly with std::size_t, std::nullptr_t, etc...

In the following example, the line, if exists, is noisy: *dynamic_cast throws `std::bad_cast`.* 
    And similar example of indipensibility LSL and C++ is initializer list.

> Is there some directive specifying how should be initializer list (in C++ meaning) interpreted?

Directive as language specification exists, directive as kind of #pragma directive or whatever what could be simply changed does not.

> Could be interpretation changed e.g. from std::initializer_list into T[]?

In MSVC, no. Probably nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

```
struct Something { char c0, c1; };
Something something = { 'H', 'W' };
```

> Where is the line between C++ language and STL library?

This is not really a difference between *C++ language* and *STL library* since the standard library is itself written in C++ (it makes no sense to think of them as two separate entities). The main point is in distinguishing which kind of element you're initializing and what constructors are available.

Most of the confusion stems from the fact that proposals and defect reports have stirred quite a bit of arguing on how curly-braces initialization are to be interpreted (cfr. [Scott Meyers articles](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.it/2014/03/if-braced-initializers-have-no-type-why.html), some of them have been [recently discussed](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.it/2016/11/help-me-sort-out-meaning-of-as.html) as well).

> Is there some directive specifying how should be initializer list (in C++ meaning) interpreted?

The only proper way to understand it is in being able to recognize the types you're using and understanding the [C++ standard](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) directives (according to the C++ version and compiler support you're using).

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Mentioned articles exactly show what confused me.